# Unable to add Anaconda environment to PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda

I have created environment `py33` under Anaconda and trying to add it to PyCharm, but addition button is dimmed:

[image]

[image]

I was unable to find any subdirectory where `OK` is available.

Answer (score 1):

I was to point to executable.

[image]

Also after restart and new environment variables came to effect PyCharm saw Anaconda options:

[image]